# Ayat in Qu'ran that refute shirk,why are they true?

Tags: quran

> Say, ˹O Prophet,˺ “Had there been other gods besides Him—as they
> claim—then they would have certainly sought a way to ˹challenge˺ the
> Lord of the Throne.”
>
> 23:91) Never did Allah take unto Himself any son,84 nor is there any
> god other than He. (Had there been any other gods) each god would have
> taken his creatures away with him, and each would have rushed to
> overpower the other.85 Glory be to Allah from all that they
> characterize Him with!
>
> Had there been therein (in the heavens and the earth) ilaha (gods) besides Allah, then verily both would have been ruined(or in chaos). Glorified be Allah, the Lord of the Throne, (High is He) above all that (evil) they associate with Him!” Quran (Surah Al-Anbiya, 22)

My question is for the first ayat,why would they challenge the lord of the throne?Isn't harmony a Godly trait?So wouldn't they all be harmonious with one another?If they are all good-being Gods-,then they would seemingly will the exact same things,that is only good and perfect things,so surah al anbiya ayat 22 also seems hard to accept for me.

Am I right?If not,why not?

Why are these verses premises true beyond all doubt?Please explain why they are true?Humility seems like a Godly trait,so they wouldn't seek to overpower each other?

Answer (score 0):

There are no religous sources to my answer because what you're asking is philosophical itself, but I will try to explain.
Any "god" should be an absolute live being, it means all of his traits should be absoulte, that's why he's a "god" and if he's not absolute and perfect, than he's not a god. With that being said, it's simple to understand that if there would be 2 gods, than they would've fought each other for the power, for the status of an absolute god, which by definition is absurd, this is exactly what is being said in these verses, that just by looking at this world and everything in it, you can tell that everything works and synchronizes with each other (and not in a constant chaos) which means there's only one who's controlling all of that, allmighty and all-knowing. If there would've been 2 and more gods, than who created who, who came first? It doesn't make sense logically, logically it makes sense to believe that if someone has created everything, than it should be the only live being, who was there all the time and who will be there all the time, this is why it's called 'faith', you just believe in that because it makes sens to you, but there are no '100% facts' about this all being the truth, because if there were, than the whole purpose of faith would've been pointless (and the testing in this life), and if you start to think about other theories, like 2 and more gods, than some questions are starting to appear, which logically don't have any answer, so you can also just choose to believe that, but if choosing between 2 things to believe, for me it's logical to choose one which doesn't have unanswered questions in the theory of it.